# Can I password protect new files added to an archived 7zip file? When I add news files to an archive, they're not password protected

Tags: windows, zip, 7-zip, archiving, file-archiver

Currently I have a 7-zip archive that I made full of videos and pictures that are password protected. Now, I have more videos and pictures that I want to put in the archive, however when I do, they're not influenced by the password that I put in place when I originally made the archive.

Do I have to keep making a new archive to make sure all files are password protected in the zip file, or is there something I'm missing?

Or do I have to use another program that allows me to do that?

Comment: I have the same issue with winrar.  It looks like the design is so that each file can have its own password.  In Winrar, you can open the archive, and right click and set password on selected files.